# How to check if a given string is valid Regex?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test if a regular expression is a valid one in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825025/test-if-a-regular-expression-is-a-valid-one-in-php)

```
 <?php 

    $subject = "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.";    
    $pattern = 'sssss';

    if(preg_match($pattern,$subject))
    {
        echo 'true';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'false';
    }

?>
```

The above code gives me warning because the string `$pattern` is not a valid regular expression.

If I pass valid regular expression then it works fine.....

How can i check `$pattern` is valid regular expression?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095238/an-invalid-regex-pattern

Comment: or, better, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362793/regexp-that-matches-valid-regexps

Comment: or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825025/test-if-a-regular-expression-is-a-valid-one-in-php

Comment: this also helps:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778318/test-if-a-string-is-regex

Comment: Possibly least useful question + accepted answer as first result in google. But at least plenty of useful links...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just wrap `preg_match` with try catch, and consider result false, if it throws exception.

Anyway, you can take a look at [regular expression to detect a valid regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression).

Comment: Adding `@` before functions to suppress warnings / errors is Bad Practice. It will hide possible bugs from your code.

Answer (score 5):

You could write a function that throws an error if there is something wrong with the Regexp.
(Like it should have been in my opinion.)
It is bad practice to use the `@` to suppress warnings, but if you replace it with a thrown exception it should be ok.

```
function my_preg_match($pattern,$subject)
{
    $match = @preg_match($pattern,$subject);

    if($match === false)
    {
        $error = error_get_last();
        throw new Exception($error['message']);
    }
    return false;
}
```

then you can check if the regexp is correct with

```
$subject = "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.";    
$pattern = 'sssss';

try
{
    my_preg_match($pattern,$subject);
    $regexp_is_correct = true;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $regexp_is_correct = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `===` operator:

```
<?php 

    $subject = "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.";    
    $pattern = 'sssss';

    $r = preg_match($pattern,$subject);
    if($r === false)
    {
        // preg matching failed (most likely because of incorrect regex)
    }
    else
    {
        // preg match succeeeded, use $r for result (which can be 0 for no match)
        if ($r == 0) {
            // no match
        } else {
            // $subject matches $pattern
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: I fixed the syntax error (case of copy-paste mistake). And my answer gives a way of detecting if the regex is incorrect (which is was the OP asked for).

Comment: @loler how exactly? `preg_match($pattern, $subject);` is perfectly valid PHP.

Comment: @loler apparently you are misreading the OP's question. He **says** the regex is invalid. This is not a syntax error, it's a warning.

Comment: @loler no. OP's code also drops in the "false" part if there is no match. Which is something else than a regex error. Check this: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php and the remark on preg_match's documentation page: "This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE."